# Unable to add C# class library(.Net framework) as reference in Newly created Asp.Net core + Angular 2 Web Application (.Net framework)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-1.0

I have created Asp.Net Core + Angular 2 Project with .Net Framework, My project.json follows

```
{
  "dependencies": {
   "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.AngularServices": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  },
"frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Business.Logic": {
          "target": "project"
        }


      }
    }
  },

"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "appsettings.json",
      "ClientApp/dist",
      "node_modules",
      "Views",
      "web.config",
      "wwwroot"
    ],
    "exclude": [ "**.user", "**.vspscc", "**.cs", "bin", "wwwroot/dist/*.map" ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [
      "npm install",
      "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod",
      "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod"
    ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
```

I have added class library as a reference. When I try to build the project following error encountered.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(338,5): error MSB3202: The project file "..\WebApp\Business.Logic.csproj" was not found.
```

Class Library created one year before with .Net Framework 4.5.1, Now I upgrade to .Net Framework 4.6.1. Please, anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: you cannot add a project file as reference. you need to add the **.dll** file

Comment: @Aravind I Try to add class Library(.dll) as reference From solution. what I had done previous projects.

Comment: I didnt get you. Can you elaborate

Comment: I followed the steps to add reference below. right click on the Web UI project and select add reference Then Select solution from left side menu then select Business.Logic.